# ListItemClicked issue

Tags: android, list

I have a list item where i have some items in. But no matter what i click, i always get position==-1.

And when i click first position its fine but when i click second or third position my app is crushing and i am getting Logcat:

```
05-12 19:37:34.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11152): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
05-12 19:37:34.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11152): at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
```

Here is my code onListItemClicked:

```
class ListItemClicked implements OnItemClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


       int position =  parent.getSelectedItemPosition();  

       if(position==-1)            
       {           

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"first item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


       }

    }       
}
```

Please tell me if you need more info.

Comment: show the getSelectedItemPosition function its obviously an error there

Comment: how many items are there in ur list?
according to the logcat..it seems ur list has just one item..and when ur clicking the second item or any other the position returned is -1 meaning no other elements are present

Comment: meaby it beacuse item are appearing after some time beacuse i am searching for bluetooth devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you ArrayList size is 1 and you trying to get item 2 from it
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

Comment: ye i know i don t know how to change the size of it

Comment: just add more item to ArrayList arrayListObject.add();

Comment: can you show me the line you getting item from ArrayList

Comment: k i fix it thanks guys i just do  arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(0, null);
         }

Comment: u welcome so can i get best answer or up to my second comment

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `parent.getSelectedItemPosition()`, but rather use the `position` parameter. That's what it's for.

Comment: ye now it work better when i click first item i get position==0, but on second item click i am getting same error. It arraylist and meaby i can set size of it?

Comment: arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>(); and i am adding item like this: detectedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());                 
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device); meaby there is something